# How to share the text on WeChat app from my IOS(Objective c) app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift3, wechat

I'm doing the lost of search for sharing the text on WeChat app from my app but I didn't get any proper solution for these.Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code.

Comment: the issue is that I can't register my app on their developer account.

Comment: SendMessageToWXReq *req = [[SendMessageToWXReq alloc] init];
        req.text = @"My App link here";
        req.bText = YES;
        req.scene = WXSceneSession;
        //req.scene = WXSceneTimeline;
        [WXApi sendReq:req];

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed WeChat your iPhone use this code

```
 - (IBAction)shareBtnAction:(id)sender
 {
    NSString *textToShare = @"";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.facebook.com"];

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                               UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                               UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                               UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What is the UIActivityType for WeChat ?

Comment: No need to pass  UIActivityType for WeChat it will take directly all sharing app from your device.

Comment: If now showing click on more button get permission yes for we chat.

Comment: Thanks for replay and I done that, But my problem is that ----  I log in to http://admin.wechat.com/ by using QR code and I got the appID, WeChat ID, app secret.

But the issue is that I got stuck when I come to the URL and Token, according to their document( http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Getting_Started).

I can't understand how to create the URL (I need PHP developer for this?) Any one help me for this issue.

I didn't understand which type of URL they need please give me any example for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it would be helpful for you!!!

```
  @IBAction func btnExport(sender: AnyObject)
{

     let someText:String = "Hello want to share text also"
    let objectsToShare:URL = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
    let sharedObjects:[AnyObject] = [objectsToShare as AnyObject,someText as AnyObject]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems : sharedObjects, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook,UIActivityType.postToTwitter,UIActivityType.mail]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```